# How can I convert music (in MP3 or MIDI form) into a noteblock song in Minecraft on Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I am trying to possibly use a few music files, which are all MP3s and to convert them into noteblock form in minecraft (either the physical structure *OR* a .nbs file, which Note Block Studio can export to and can be used in a variety of noteblock plugins for servers). However, I'm running Mac, and it seems like Noteblock Studio is **only** for Windows. (Link: https://www.stuffbydavid.com/mcnbs)

I've tried manually transposing the music by hand (placing the noteblocks and the redstoning by hand), but it's proven to be really tedious and I need a more efficient way to convert music into noteblock form. **Are there any viable options for what I'm trying to do?** Is there some sort of Mac version of NBS, or is there an alternative program/conversion method?